# Formula Field in Process Builder for Opportunity Stage

Tags: formula

I am unable to write the formula in process builder for the criteria when Opportunity Stage equals "**Approved/Not Shipped**" OR "**Converted**"

My formula:

```
ISPICKVAL([Opportunity].StageName , Approved/Not Shipped) ||
ISPICKVAL([Opportunity].StageName , Converted)
```

Comment: Have you checked [the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5)?

Answer (score 1):

A slight change in your formula will work:-

```
OR( ISPICKVAL([Opportunity].StageName, "Approved/Not Shipped"),
       ISPICKVAL([Opportunity].StageName, "Converted") )
```

You were missing the double quotes for the stage name value.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
OR(
ISPICKVAL([Opportunity].StageName, "Approved/Not Shipped") ,
ISPICKVAL([Opportunity].StageName , "Converted") 
)
```